# jQuery Scirpt not begin called- Flask app

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

im trying to send requests without refreshing the pae using ajax requests.

Watching the google event listerner when i i click the submit button my script is not begin called.

script.js

```
$("#new_app_b").click(function(event) { 
    //prevent submit
    event.preventDefault();      
    //do things on submit
    $.ajax({
        data : {
            data_app : $('#data_app').val(),
            time_app : $('#time_app').val(),
            id : $('#id').val()
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "/update",
        beforeSend: function(){
         //before send data
        },
        success: function(data){
            // the data
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
  });
```

in layout.html i call this in the

in page html the part with the form is like this it has the {% extends 'layout.html' %} and the form is the the blockcontent and is begin displayed correctly it has 300+ lines so i wont post it all.

```
<form action="/update" method='POST' id="new_app">
    <input name="id" id="id" type="hidden" value="{{ pratica[0][1] }}"> 
    </input> 
    {% for cell in pratica %}
       {% if cell[0] == 'data_app' %}
          <td><input name="data_app" id="data_int" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                type="text" value="{{ cell[1] }}"/></td>
       {% elif cell[0] == 'time_app' %}
          <td><input name="time_app" id="ora_app" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                type="text" value="{{ cell[1] }}"/></td>
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    <td>
       <button id="new_app_b" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
       </button>
    </td>
</form>
```

while the /update controller is just like:

```
@app.route("/update", methods=['GET','POST'])
def update():
    print("request: ")
    print("id: " + request.form['id_pratica'])
    print("data_app: " + request.form['data_app'])
    print("time_app: " + request.form['time_app'])
    return ''
```

Comment: use document ready function
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new_app_b").click(function(event) {
  
  });
});

Comment: Your code is fine it works, i tried it and it got called when i click the button. Put an ``alert('test')`` after the ``event.preventDefault();`` and you will see that it enters that ''function''. If your controller doenst get triggered the problem is in the URL that you call inside the ajax

Comment: Tausif, ive added it but still not working. In put the alert to test it but still is not working.

Comment: Tausif, ive added it but still not working. In put the alert to test it but still is not working. I think the problem is that im calling the script in layout.html and then using {% extends 'layout.html' %} on top of the html page that is using it. Any guess? i cant move all the code from layout.html to tthis page . Should i move the script instance directly in this html file?? if so can ii put it inside the<body> ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So ive found the solution and this is what i did:

I moved the  into the child template, using a block block like so:

```
{% block scripts %}
  {{ super() }}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and put that block on top of the content block, and then i call the block in the layout.html file like so

```
{% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
```

in the  tag, and now is begin loaded and called when it needs to.